# Building an empty portable executable

Tags: windows, 64-bit, executable

I'm trying to build my own portable executable (.exe) in Windows with just x64 machine code.  I tried building just a blank program in C++ in release mode and PE explorer says it has seven sections.

I believe only 2 are required (.text and .data) for an empty program?  I just don't know how to calculate all these magic numbers.

Anyone have any tips or guides on creating a PE?  I'd even be willing to pay someone to help create one.

Comment: Please format in paragraphs for easy reading. It might help your question if you include some of what you have already tried and any errors generated from the attempt.

Comment: I'd start with the official [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg463119.aspx) if you haven't already. Investigate how things fit together like a puzzle (e.g. generate an EXE and change [the DOS stub](http://www.reverse-engineering.info/PE_Information/dosstub.htm)). The [EXE Format](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) part of the DJGPP documentation was helpful to me as well. Note that "block" on the DJGPP documentation is "page" in the PE/COFF spec, hence the `e_cblp` (Entry: Count of Bytes in Last Page) member of `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` in `<winnt.h>`.

Comment: I personally found [this](https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE101) most helpful to get started (there's a 64bit version if you click around), it doesn't immediately overload you with all the options, just the things you really need to know to get started.